# How to pass data to nested child components vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I get how to pass data from parent to child with props in a situation like:

```
<template>
<div>
      <div v-for="stuff in content" v-bind:key="stuff.id">
        <ul>
          <li>
            {{ stuff.items }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: stuff,
  props: ['content'],
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And then bind the data to the component in the parent component like,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <stuff v-bind:content="stuffToPass"></stuff>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import stuff from './stuff.vue';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      stuffToPass: [
        {id: 1, items: 'foo'},
        {id: 2, items: 'bar'},
        {id: 3, items: 'baz'}
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    stuff
  }
}
</script>
```

But say I have the root component, and I want to pass data to the stuff component, like in the above, but when I have a number of other components like **parent > x > y > stuff**, and it's still the stuff component that will ultimately be receiving that data, I don't know how to do that.

I heard of provide/inject, but I'm not sure that's the appropriate use, or at least I couldn't get it working.

Then I tried passing props, but then I found myself trying to bind a prop to a component to pass as a prop to a child component and that doesn't sound right, so then I just re-wrote my components in the 'stuff' component, but I feel that's probably re-writing way to much code to be close to reasonable.

Comment: You should use https://github.com/vuejs/vuex

Comment: yes, i am going to be using vuex. the motivation for the question though is that if the 'stuff' component will be used for/in other components aswell, i will need to pass data through a specific parent

Comment: You can pass data from the parent to x then x to y and in the last y to stuff component. Or you can use any state management library such as redux or flux.

Comment: I suggest you see [this.$parent](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-parent), [this.$root](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root), [provide-inject](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject)

Comment: so then in parent compnent: <script>  let dataToPass = {  [id: 1, data: 'foo'],..} export default { provide : stuffToPass }

Comment: and then in the stuff component i would <script> export default { inject: ['stuffToPass', 'otherPossibleDependecies',...]

Comment: You could use an [EventBus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860)

Answer (score 2):

there are a few possibilities to pass data **parent > x > y > stuff**

- **props** - applicable but you would have to pipe the data through all components...
- **store (vuex)** - applicable but could become complicated to handle
- **event bus** - the most flexible and direct way

below, a simple example on how to implement the event bus:

```
// src/services/eventBus.js

import Vue from 'vue';
export default new Vue();
```

the code from where you want to emit the event:

```
// src/components/parent.vue

<script>
import EventBus from '@/services/eventBus';

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    eventHandler(val) {
      EventBus.$emit('EVENT_NAME', val);
    },
  },
  ...
};
</script>
```

the code for where you want to listen for the event:

```
// src/components/stuff.vue

<script>
import EventBus from '@/services/eventBus';

export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('EVENT_NAME', val => {
      // do whatever you like with "val"
    });
  },
  ...
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use watchers or computed properties https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

```js
const Stuff = Vue.component('stuff', {
  props: ['content'],
  template: `<div>
      <div v-for="stuff in content" v-bind:key="stuff.id">
        <ul>
          <li>
            {{ stuff.items }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>`
});

const Adapter = Vue.component('adapter', {
  components: { Stuff },
  props: ['data'],
  template: `<div>
        <Stuff :content="newData"/>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      newData: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.changeData();
  },
  watch: {
    data: {
      deep: true,
      handler: function() {
        this.changeData();
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeData() {
      this.newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    }
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Adapter },
  data() {
    return {
      stuffToPass: [
        { id: 1, items: 'foo' },
        { id: 2, items: 'bar' },
        { id: 3, items: 'baz' }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.stuffToPass.push({ id: this.stuffToPass.length + 1, items: 'new' });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.1/vue.js"></script>
   <div id="app">
      <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
      <Adapter :data="stuffToPass"/>
    </div>
```